# Linked List createList vs initNode functions

Tags: c, arrays, list, dynamic

Im supposed to create a linked list and I was given a header file that contains the functions:

```
listNode *initNode(int value);
listNode* createList();
```

Im kind of confused at what the createList function should be doing...

In the initNode it would like something like:

```
listNode *someNode;
someNode = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
someNode->next = NULL;
someNode->value = value;
return someNode;
```

What should the createList function be doing? I would call it in my test program but I don't really know what to do with it.

Comment: My guess would be that `createList` will manage the linked list for you, but they also give you the option of just making a node and managing it yourself. Just a guess though, I'm not familiar with that particular library.

Comment: Also, I suggest adding tags to specify the language you're using. I'm assuming C.

Comment: I just looked at some other files I got and it said this:

Create some node to be the head of the list and then set the next pointer equal to NULL and return that node.

Would that just be:
    listNode*anyNode;
    anyNode->next = NULL

Comment: where did you get the library you're using? If its available online, I'll take a look to try to figure out their intended use

Comment: maybe `listNode* createList(void) { return NULL; }`, `listNode *head = createList();`

Comment: there should be a proper documentation around .. what is the name of the library?

Comment: Are you only supposed to be *using* these functions, or are you supposed to be *implementing* them?

Comment: The function is called createList. It is fair to assume it should create a list. Now, if it should create a list that contains some data, then it becomes unclear what data to include. Perhaps it should create an empty list. This seems plausible. Now ask yourself how do you want to represent an empty list, and create that.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to implement the LinkedList with a dumb header node, you may do it in the `createList` method. Or if you wish use another `struct` with more information about list, something like

```
struct LinkedList {
    listnode *header;
    size_t size;
};
```

you may also malloc and init it in your `createList` method.

Answer (score 0):

`createList` may allocate memory for a new list structure, usually creating a new list head structure, a "handle" with which you may manipulate the list later.